# Existe-t-il un adverbe pour signifier "pendant le jour"?

Tags: choix-de-mot

En traduisant un texte anglais, j'ai eu besoin de l'adverbe [nocturnement](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=nocturnement&dicoid=LITTRE1872) (de nuit, pendant la nuit, synonyme de nuitamment). Je voulais par curiosité savoir s'il existait de même un adverbe pour le jour.

Je n'ai trouvé, de façon surprenante, aucun dictionnaire qui n'indexe *diurnement*, que j'aurais spontanément utilisé.

Comment: C'est un texte plutôt ancien (lui-même traduit du latin), un traité de médecine

Comment: Vous ne pouvez pas vous passer de l'adverbe négatif « pas » dans cette construction, ce qui donne « aucun dictionnaire qui n'indexe pas diurnement », ce qui est du ,non-sens. Les seuls cas où il est permis d'utiliser « ne » sans « pas » : http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/O_a_la_negation.htm.

Comment: Ma seule référence pour ce qui est permis, c'est l'usage

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse "Aucun" ne se trouve pas dans la relative et n'a donc pas d'effet dans cette partie de la phrase comme élément de modification du verbe. Considérer que l'on a tout aussi bien la possibilité « aucun dictionnaire qui indexe diurnement » et « qui » dans ce cas n'a certainement pas « aucun » pour antécédent; pourquoi aurait-il « aucun » pour antécédent dans le cas « qui n'indexe diurnement ». Cet usage auquel réfère l'OP n'est pas un usage attesté et c'est probablement le produit de récentes tendances qui seront réfutées avant trop longtemps. Où est-ce attesté ?

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Pas du tout, ça c'est parfaitement correct (dû à la présence d'un élément négatif (jamais, point, guère, etc.)); je crois que cela est clair.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Il y a peut-être d'autre possibilités que celle que j'ai choisie pour ma correction initiale (laquelle a été reçue par un rollback), mais je pense qu'il n'y en possiblement pas de plus courte.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119442/discussion-between-zehontee-bonteuse-and-lph).

Comment: @LPH J'arrive après la bataille mais ta "correction" était essentiellement du charabia...

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne comprends pas… « au contraire de quoi » se dit très bien : « Au contraire de quoi ,le séjourner dans l'immédiat n'aura su qu'éveiller une séquence de figures ambivalentes, coinclusives … » (https://books.google.fr/books?id=8A10TINyrSsC&pg=PT206&dq=%22au+contraire+de+quoi%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9srqPj9fuAhUp8-AKHSYKAQ0Q6AEwAnoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22au%20contraire%20de%20quoi%22&f=false)

Comment: _qui, loin d'éclairer le problème qu'elles étaient censer résoudre, n'auront fait que le précipiter dans le registre d'une spécularité sans issue._ hahaahaha. hahahaha. :)

Answer (score 3):

***Nocturnement*** est très rare donc peu d'espoir de voir ***diurnement*** émerger:
[image]

Ce qu'on rencontre le plus souvent, ce sont les locutions adverbiales ***de nuit*** et ***de jour***:

[image]

Note: Il existe aussi les adverbes *journellement* ou *quotidiennement* mais ils ne sont pas utilisables ici car ils se réfèrent à la journée de vingt-quatre heures, pas à la journée en opposition avec la nuit.

Comment: En plus, ces locutions sont plus faciles à prononcer...

Comment: *Journellement* est en sympathie avec quotidiennement. Je me vois mal exécuter une tâche journellement après le coucher du soleil ... Mais je peux la faire qu'une fois, journellement.

Comment: @Personne Oui, je les avais écartées d'office, mais je viens de les ajouter avec une explication. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

On peut utiliser [diurnement](https://conjf.cactus2000.de/show_adj.fr.php?adj=diurne), apparemment, bien que ce ne soit pas un mot dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/diurnement).

On trouve de nos jours un nombre assez important [d'occcurrences](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nocturnement%22&lr=lang_fr&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1fr,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB2_qhn9buAhW96uAKHTN4AqYQpwUIJA&biw=1920&bih=1005&dpr=1) de cet adverbe.

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nocturnement&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnocturnement%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnocturnement%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Comment: On ne doit pas avoir la même définition de ce que signifie "assez important"...

Comment: @jlliagre Il faut l'avouer, ce n'est pas énorme, mais 9 cas dans les livres, ça se traduit parfois par beaucoup dans tout le matériel imprimé : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nocturnement%22&safe=active&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0jbvprNbuAhVC8xQKHVxABtoQ_AUICigA&biw=1920&bih=1005&dpr=1

Comment: @jlliagre Y a-t-il un corpus qui élimine les résultats où ce sont des citations de textes d'une autre époque dans des textes modernes ou des textes qui justement étudient le mot sur lequel on cherche des exemples d'emplois ?

Comment: @Zéhontée Pas que je sache. Il y a quelques occurrences "vraies", mais ce sont des textes littéraires où l'auteur aura recherché un mot qui sort de l'ordinaire. Les fréquences d'utilisation relatives des mots proches sont plus pertinentes qu'une courbe solitaire, encore que si on regarde les pourcentages, on voit qu'il s'agit d'un mot   très rare (une apparition tous les 166 millions de mots)

Comment: @LPH la plupart des occurrences trouvées par Google sont des entrées de dictionnaires. Ce n'est pas un signe de bonne santé pour un mot...

Comment: @jlliagre Rien que dans le domaine des vidéos on en trouve plus de 150 : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nocturnement%22&source=lmns&tbm=vid&bih=1007&biw=1920&safe=active&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwib4ImSoN3uAhWL_4UKHYYXA-0Q_AUoAnoECAEQAg

Comment: Je parlais des occurrences de Google Book mais ok, je suis surpris par le nombre de celles associées à des vidéos.